# Mongodb query for counting number of unique fields grouped by other field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like this

```
Product={
  brand :String,
  model:String,
  price:String,
  variant:String}
```

I need a query that will return number of od models per brand.
For instance lets say that collection is populated with the following data

```
{brand: "bmw", model:"x5", variant:"200hp", price:"30000"}
{brand: "bmw", model:"x5", variant:"300hp", price:"40000"}
{brand: "bmw", model:"x3", variant:"100hp", price:"15000"}
{brand: "fiat", model:"punto", variant:"100hp", price:"10000"}
{brand: "fiat", model:"punto", variant:"80hp", price:"9000"}
```

I need a query that will return followig data:

```
[{brand:"bmw", number_of_models:"2"}, {"brand":"fiat", number_of_models:"1"}]
```

Any help would be greatly appretiated

Comment: Hi,  Please see my solution. that works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongodb aggregate query `$group`. I have used above given sample data and tested it. This below query works fine.

```
Product.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "brand": "$brand",
            "model": "$model"
        },
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.brand",
        "number_of_models": { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        brand: "$_id",
        number_of_models: 1
    }
}   
])
```

**Result** :

```
    [{
        "number_of_models" : 2,
        "brand" : "bmw"
    },
    {
        "number_of_models" : 1,
        "brand" : "fiat"
    }]
```